# Django Newbie error: - TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am a total newbie to python Django and would like to know why are views not being created.
here's my urls.py which is under myproject.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf.urls import url
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = ['',
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('myapp/', include('myapp.url'))
]
```

here's my view.py which is in myapp folder

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def hello(request):
    return render(request,"myapp/templates/hello.html", {})
```

here's my url.py in myapp folder

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = ['', url('hello/', 'views.hello', name='hello'),]
```

and here's the complete traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/PycharmProjects/Learning-Django/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    url('myapp/', include('myapp.url'))
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/PycharmProjects/Learning-Django/myproject/myapp/url.py", line 3, in <module>
    urlpatterns = ['', url('hello/', 'views.hello', name='hello'),]
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 13, in url
    return re_path(regex, view, kwargs, name)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Learning-Django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

i've read a few tutorials and the code is being referred from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_url_mapping.htm but not sure why i am getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `url` with `path`:

```
# main urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.url'))
]

# app urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .view import hello

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', hello, name='hello'),
]
```

As you can see in [**`documetation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/), `path` has been introduced(from Django>=2.0), so you don't have to use `url` here. The tutorial you are following is for older versions, so it is using `url` with regex to generate URLs.

Comment: understood however that leads me to django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern '' is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of path() and/or re_path() instances.
        HINT: Try removing the string ''. The list of urlpatterns should not have a prefix string as the first element.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

Comment: um, did you remove [ '', ...] (the empty string) from `urlpatterns` as the answer suggested?